# Same MongoDB Atlas (pymongo) query has different execution time on different servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I wanted to know why am I getting different exection times for same queries that are run on different servers. I am using Mongo DB through Atlas, and am running the query on the **same database and collection**.

To test this out I created a python script which generates some random large data and then calls the update_one() function in pymongo with upsert=True. I am using line_profiler library (https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) to check the execution time of each statement.

When I run this on my local machine, the update_one() call takes 0.3 seconds. When I tried the same on one of my servers, it took around 4 seconds. On another server it took 1.8 seconds. It's taking the same time (±0.2 seconds) on repeated tries too, for all of them. Shouldn't they take the same amount of time regardless of where it's called from, since the query is running on the same Atlas instance?

Any info/help on this would be appreciated!

**Here's the script that I used to test this out:**

```py
# =========================================================
# filename: mongo_profile.py
# Python 3.9.0
# pip 20.3.3

# pip install pymongo
# pip install dnspython
# pip install line_profiler

# Run:
# 1. kernprof -l mongo_profile.py
# 2. python -m line_profiler mongo_profile.py.lprof
# =========================================================

import pymongo
import hashlib

@profile
def mongo_function(data):
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient("<mongo-atlas-connection-url>")
    database = connection["test_database"]
    collection = database["profiling_collection"]
    collection.update_one(
        {"name": "collection1"},
        {"$set": {"data": data}},
        upsert=True
    )

data = []
for i in range(20000):
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(str(i).encode("utf-8"))
    m.update(b"Some Text")
    data.append({
        "index": i,
        "hash": m.hexdigest()[0:8]
    })

mongo_function(data)
```

Comment: Do all these servers have the same hardware configuration? Same mongodb version? Are they located in the same place(DC)?

Comment: @rdas I don't have mongodb installed on my servers since I'm using their cloud service (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). If I was running a local instance, I could have assumed the issue was related hardware.

Answer (score 0):

See [mongodb 4x slower than sqlite, 2x slower than csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605360/mongodb-4x-slower-than-sqlite-2x-slower-than-csv/65607407#65607407) for how to properly benchmark crud operations and a list of some of the operations that are included in the times as you are collecting them.